# C# WPF SelectionChangedEvent - reset selection - better options?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, caliburn.micro

I have a `datagridview` populated with items and I am using a `SelectionChanged` event to populate `textboxes` from that data when selected.

If I make a selection, everything works.  If I click elsewhere in the App and then come back to click the `SelectionChanged` event again on the same item - it doesn't work.

According to MSDN:

"This event occurs whenever there is a **change** to a selection."

[MSDN SelectionChangedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

So it appears that despite clicking elsewhere, resetting the Textboxes - the selected item is not changing as the SelectionChanged event no longer triggers - click on another item and it works, click back again and it works - but click on it, reset textboxes, click it again - nothing happens, this includes clicking in the `datagridview` itself in a blank area.

**XAML**:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="TimeView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="10 50 10 10" 
CanUserAddRows="False" Visibility="{Binding StartTiming}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="SelectedTimeChangeEvent">
                        <cal:Parameter Value="$eventArgs" />
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public void SelectedTimeChangeEvent(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TimeData addedRow in e.AddedItems)
    {
        TbID = addedRow.ID;
        TbDate = addedRow.Date;
        TbStartTime = addedRow.StartTime;
        TbDescription = addedRow.Description;
    }
}
```

Since I am using MVVM and Caliburn, TimeView is connected to an ICollection, which is in turn connected to an ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<TimeData>? _timeCollection;

public ObservableCollection<TimeData>? TimeCollection
{
    get { return _timeCollection; }
    set
    {
        _timeCollection = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TimeCollection);
    }
}

private ICollectionView? _timeView;

public ICollectionView? TimeView
{
    get { return _timeView; }
    set
    {
        _timeView = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TimeView);
    }
}
```

There is a work around, which is the following after populating the Textboxes:

```
TimeView = null;
TimeView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TimeCollection);
```

This works, but I thought that there might be a "deselect" option that would be better than repopulating every time a selection is made, one of my Datagrids contains 15,000 items, and it is still instant, but seems overkill to populate it every time a selection is made.

Comment: The posted code as it is doesn't make much sense. It looks like in your foreach loop you are overwriting the same properties TbId, TbDate etc. I assume that this are properties defined on the ViewModel class? Also the line `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TimeCollection);` and the `TimeView` property are redundant. You can bind the DataGrid directly to the TimeCollection as DataGrid will implicitly retrieve the associated default view on its own.

Comment: To correct your misunderstanding: the SelectionChanged event is only raised when the selected item has changed and not if the focus changes. Clicking the same successively item only raises the event for the first time the selected item changes (i.e. it is added to the DataGrid.SelectedItems collection).

Comment: The SelectionChanged event is a routed event. It should not be handled in the view model directly. You could handle it in code-behind and pass the selected items to the view model directly (e.g. by calling a method) or via a data binding through an intermediate property. When you are stuck on how to move data from view to view model, interaction triggers are never the solution in an MVVM environment.

Comment: To make it clear: you want to extract the data from the selected items to set some text boxes or properties (???) and on extraction completed you want to unselect the DataGrid selected items?

Comment: I don't know why you think it is a misunderstanding - when I explicitly link to the MSDN  site stating that the event is only raised when it changes?  The reason it is an ICollection is for filtering on the Datagridview, but that has nothing to do with the question.  Yes, I want to deselect, hence the title of the post being "reset selection".

Comment: *"I don't know why you think it is a misunderstanding"* - because you wrote: *"If I click elsewhere in the App and then come back to click the SelectionChanged event again on the same item - it doesn't work."* You obviously misunderstood the behavior or the circumstances that make the DataGrid raise this event. *"[...] but that has nothing to do with the question."* - Then don't post it! I was just trying to understand your environment. *"[..] hence the title of the post being "reset selection""* - The flow wasn't really clear like *when* and *what* to deselect. Sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That isn't a misunderstanding, it is going further to say - look the behaviour matches, it is still selected when clicking elsewhere hence the problem.  Why would I cut a bit out of my code that goes to the way the view is made? The fact that it is set out that way is not relevant to the question, but may be relevant to the answer. The link you posted, describes the post I made - title with the problem, yep, introduce the problem, yep, show the research, yep, post the code - yep....I don't know what more you want?

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend bindings, they automaticly reset when nothing is selected

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedTime}" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TimeView}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTime}">
    ...
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>

public TimeData SelectedTime
{
    get { return _selectedTime; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTime = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedTime);
    }
}
```

also there is this neet feature

```
protected virtual void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
```

so you can write

```
    set { SetValue(ref _selectedTime, value) }
```